# Centroid coordinates of an irregular quadrilateral within a rectangular plane

Tags: polar-coordinates, rectangles, quadrilateral, centroid

I am developing a robotic project; the robot moves within a rectangular area 80cm x 180cm on a level horizontal surface. The area is bounded by four vertical walls, the robot has onboard four ultra-sonic sensors which are located at 90 degrees from each other and provide continuous distance readings in cm in all four directions, such that at any point in time the distance from the robot to the vertical wall is known. Currently the area of the irregular quadrilateral, and its internal angles can be calculated. My question, is there a method for calculating the x and y coordinates of the robot(centroid of the quadrilateral) within the rectangle?

I have attached an image of the problem, detailing all known values and those values which I have calculated. Diagram of Example: [QuestionV2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5krZ.jpg)

Apologies I had incorrectly described the example. The red lines are calculated values, while the four black lines from R are the ultra-sonic readings. Each ultra sonic reading comes with its direction, i.e. Front, Back, Left, or right. So in the example the RC reading is marked Front, RA as Back, RD as left, and RB as right.

I have found that I can install an on-board compass, which would provide a compass bearing

Comment: Please upload images as part of the question, if they are needed to understand the question.

Comment: Your diagram is confusing. If the black lines are the ultrasound, this is not going to bounce off the walls back to the sensor unless the beam is perpendicular to the wall. I don't understand how the red lines eg AB are measured while the black lines eg AR are calculated. It looks like this ought to be the other way round. However answers to these questions will not solve the flaw that David Stork has pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

No... not if all you have are four distances (and not information as to which wall).  Both the red and blue robots have the same set of four distances, but they lie in different places.

[image]